# Как найти последнюю строку Excel и записать туда данные

Tags: node.js, excel

Как найти последнюю строку Excel с помощью библиотеки xlsx-populate

Comment: Что такое "последняя строка" в вашем понимании?

Comment: @Kromster, автор имеет в виду строку, после которой ничего нет. В PHPExcel это называется `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();`. В пакете xlsx-populate я аналог не нашел. ТС, я думаю, вам нужно методом перебора построчно искать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const value=workbook.sheet("Sheet1").usedRange().value().length;
```

usedRange() - вытаскивает все значения с листа. Таким образом найдём сколько строк уже занято. Конечно это будет последней строкой, если все найденые  строки будут заполнены, поэтому ответ не полный